# Rendering physical suns and sky in Maya NOT as a alpha

Tags: alpha, maya

Im trying to render a animation but the sky is saved as an alpha. it shows up in the render window, but when i look at the files there alpha channels so when i put it into final cut to create a video from the image sequence there is no sky.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Maybe [gamedev.se] or [graphicdesign.se]?

Comment: no worries! see you over there :)